# ZigBee multicasting

Tags: multicast, xbee, zigbee

How can I create groups in a ZigBee PRO network to multicast these groups from the coordinator?

I am using XBee s2 modules in API mode.

I want send only one multicast message that has multiple nodes as the destination; some kind of broadcast message but not for all devices.
I think that the 16-bit address is for this propose, but I can't change the 16-bit address.

Is there any functionality to create groups in ZigBee pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using c# I was able to create a datagridview table with multiple xbee modules in it. Using their 64bit addresses and a column that I could use to group specific modules together (ie. group A, B, C, etc) I was able to loop through the table and communicate to a specific group.

Comment: Thank you, Finally I implement it on my app and I use broadcast. I think is not the best way to do it. Maybe I will try the binding table in the future.  I would appreciate if you can explain it better or show some example . Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

From experience and based on the [XBee ZB documentation](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000976_W.pdf), I would say that those modules do not currently support ZigBee Multicast Addressing.  I searched that PDF for "multicast" and had zero matches (but 159 matches for broadcast).

Comment: Thank you tomlogic. I read something for multicast messages using the binding table. I need to read more about that. Have you experience using the binding table for this purposes?. Best Regards

Comment: The binding table may have been a feature in an early firmware release, but I don't believe it's present in the current firmware.