# How to multicast a message to a destination group in zigbee network?

Tags: zigbee

How can I configure a ZigBee network to multicast some message from the coordinator?

I am using API mode in XBee s2 modules.

I want send a message that has multiple nodes as the destination. Some kind of broadcast message but not for all devices.
Is there any functionality to multicast in ZigBee s2..? Is this can be done through XCTU?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [the answer I wrote back in 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30381998/266392), and I don't believe there's any new support for multicasting.  I know that for broadcast, nodes will retransmit a message 3 times to ensure that all nodes receive a copy of it, so there's high overhead for large networks.

I think that you are better of sending multiple unicast messages to limit network traffic.

Comment: is this mean there is no way to multicast a message as we send it in broadcast, @tomlogic. what can i do for what i want

Comment: Correct.  You cannot send multicast.  You could send broadcast, and then have some indicator in the payload (an application-layer indicator) of which module group should process/accept the message.  This would require extra processing by your host processor, but would essentially be a filtered broadcast.